# Delegating class methods to an object in ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, jruby

I am trying to wrap calls to a singleton in a class (because I do not want the rest of the code to know that they are talking to a singleton), and I looked at the delegate module.

In my code, I have something like this:

```
class HideSingleton
  @@obj = SingletonClass.instance # x is an instance of SingletonClass
  # I want to be able to say HideSingleton.blah,
  # where 'blah' is instance method of SingletonClass instance (i.e., 'x')
  SimpleDelegator.new @@obj.field
end

class SingletonClass < BaseClass
  attr_reader :field
  def initialize
    @field = SimpleDelegator.new super(BaseClass Constructor params)
  end
end
```

Then in irb:

```
> require 'singleton_class'
> x = SingletonClass.new
> x.blah  # 'blah' is a method that is present in BaseClass instance
> require 'hide_singleton'
> y = HideSingleton
```

How can I do `y.blah`?

Comment: Do you mean `x = SingletonClass.instance` in your irb example? given that you are using the singleton stdlib.

Comment: that's right, just edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: So `SingletonClass` includes `Singleton`? or does `BaseClass`?

Comment: BaseClass -> no singleton. SingletonClass -> subclass of BaseClass, but includes Singleton. It's the recommended way to do it, I have heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simpler implementation of what you are trying to do, but to accomplish the hidden singleton class that delegates to a singleton class, you can do the following:

```
require 'delegate'
require 'forwardable'

class BaseClass
  def blah
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class SingletonClass < BaseClass
  attr_reader :field
  def initialize
    @field = SimpleDelegator.new(BaseClass.new)
  end
end

class HideSingleton
  def self.obj
    @@obj ||= SingletonClass.new.field
  end

  def self.method_missing *args
    obj.send *args
  end
end
```

You can then make the following calls:

```
x = SingletonClass.new
x.blah
hi
=> nil
HideSingleton.blah
hi
=> nil
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have stated my question a bit more clearly.  I am trying to delegate everything to the Singleton class, so perhaps def_delegators would not be suitable? What would you advise in light of this new information I have given you?

Comment: I made a simple modification so that you can use method_missing on the HideSingleton class to delegate to the delegator object.

Comment: Thank you very much. Beautiful solution. Just one more question: I have heard that method_missing is an order of magnitude slower than calling regular methods... Would this make a tangible performance difference if I expect to use this code frequently (say, every HTTP request in rails)?

Comment: Probably not, but I would recommend benchmarking this if you are worried about performance. If you do find that method_missing is actually a noticeable difference then you'll have to explicitly define the methods you want to delegate, in which case you won't be able to simply say: delegate everything to this other class, you'll have to explicitly say that each method is delegated to a specific delegator. In general anytime you don't define specific methods for delegation you are using method_missing anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

There are some gotchas to be aware of:

HideSingleton Class itself still has several methods (from Object and Module) and those methods would be called on HideSingleton, not SingletonClass. For example, if we had different constants in the classes like this:

```
class SingletonClass < BaseClass
  SingletonConst = :foo
end

class HideSingleton
  HideConst = :bar
end
```

Then calling the class method constants on both classes results in:

```
SingletonClass.constants
  #=> [:SingletonConst]

HideSingleton.constants
  #=> [:HideConst]
```

The same is true for any of the standard methods (const_get, class_eval, dup, respond_to?, etc).  To avoid this you would need to unload the the methods in HideSingleton that you wanted to pass through to SingletonClass (or explicitly forward them).