# extend an initiated instance to a Class ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
class Myobject
  def initialize(numberofcows,numberofdogs)
    @numberofcows = numberofcows
    @numberofdogs = numberofdogs
  end
  def cows
    @numberofcows
  end
  def dogs
     @numberofdogs
  end
end
```

#### Define constant:

```
Boo = Myobject.new(5,10)
```

#### Extend class:

```
class Foo
   extend Boo
end
```

How do I extend all the methods from an initiated object into another class?

```
Foo.cows => 5
Foo.dog  => 10
```

Myobject is a class that reads from a YAML file and creates methods from it.  They are application settings.  I need to add those dynamically assigned methods to another class.

Comment: You can't extend an object. Can your describe your actual problem instead, so that we can provide you with a proper solution?

Comment: This sounds like it's related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529925/add-methods-from-initiated-instance-variable-to-module-rails-ruby), which you posted just 11 minutes prior. Is this truly a distinct question or just a clarification/reduction of the previous question (in which case you should edit your previous question instead of posting a new one).

Comment: I rewrote it and will delete the other. I think this is more clear.

Comment: `extend` is a special keyword, but I think you're looking for setting what class inheritance: `class MyClass < MyParent`.

Comment: @prieber: I'm know sure whether inheritance is the right call here. Apperently, OP is trying to make *instance methods* from an object available as *class methods* in another class.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997990/delegating-class-methods-to-an-object-in-ruby

Comment: If I understand your question correctly--and I'm not confident that I do--could you read the YAML file to create a module `MyModule` containing instance methods `cows` and `dogs` (instead of adding those instance methods to `Myobject`)? Then you could simply execute `Myobject.include MyModule` and `Foo.extend MyModule`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, that is correct, but it creates an instance of the classs depending on the file  and scoping parameters. So I need to extend the instances methods

Comment: I don't follow. Nothing I said causes an instance of either `Myobject` or `Foo` to be created.

Comment: My example shows an instance. Your solution does not solve problem. But I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: By `extend Bob` do you mean you want all the methods of `Bob`, which are the instance methods of `Bob.class #=> Myobject`, to become class methods of `Foo` (in which case the same result obtains with any instance of `Myobject`)?

Comment: @prieber: "`extend` is a special keyword". No, it isn't. In fact, it is neither a keyword, nor is it in any way special. It is just a method like any other method. In fact, you can trivially implement it yourself: `class Object; def extend(*modules) modules.each do |mod| mod.extend_object(self) end end end`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're very smart, I understand.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes, the instance methods of Bob need to become class methods, of Foo. However, to make clear, an initated instance method of class. Each instance is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't extend a object*. Without your actual use-case, it's hard to provide a definitive answer, so here are a few alternatives.

* Unless that object is a module, but let's not get technical here.

## Using `Forwardable`

The [`Forwardable`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module can help you define delegators. However, it won't play very nicely with dynamic objects.

```rb
class Foo
  class << self
    extend Forwardable

    def_delegators :my_object, :cows, :dogs

    def my_object
      @my_object ||= MyObject.new(5, 10)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
Foo.cows # => 5
Foo.dog  # => 10
```

## Using a "dynamic" delegator

If your `MyObject` class has dynamic methods, you can make a dynamic delegator that will call any public method of your `MyObject` instance.

```rb
class Foo
  class << self
    def setting(method)
      my_object.public_send(method)
    end

    private

    def my_object
      @my_object ||= MyObject.new(5, 10)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
Foo.setting('cows') # => 5
Foo.setting('dogs') # => 10
```

## Avoiding meta-programmation altogether

I would argue that this is a bad usage of meta-programmation to begin with. If you want to navigate a YAML/JSON structure, you should do it without meta-programmtion.

For instance, given a YAML like this:

```
---
cows: 5
dogs: 10
```

You could write the following.

```rb
class Foo
  class << self
    def setting(key)
      settings[key]
    end

    private

    def settings
      @settings ||= YAML.load_file('settings.yaml')
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
Foo.setting('cows') # => 5
Foo.setting('dogs') # => 10
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't delegate every method I need within my_object, it's too large, and dynamic, based on how my_object is initialized. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529925/add-methods-from-initiated-instance-variable-to-module-rails-ruby, I will be deleting soon, but it will give another example.

Comment: I'll reiterate the comment I made on your question. Without your actual context, it's hard to give a relevant answer. If you update your question with additional information, I'll update my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: See additional context, above

Comment: You're method might work, If I dynamically loop through the methods of my_object. I will try it.

Comment: I would advise against doing this. Unnecessary meta-programmation will make your code brittle, hard to read, hard to test, and hard to maintain.

Comment: *"You can't extend a object"* Not sure what this is supposed to mean. I have to assume you are stating that you cannot extend an object with an instance of a `Class`. You can only extend an object with a `Module`

Comment: @Richard-Degenne, your answer was great, I got what I needed working.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Maybe I should rephrase that. The idea is that you can't write `extend x` where `x` is an object. I've always used "extend" as a transitive verb with a direct object, as in *"This class extends this module"*.